# How to make a div full screen and scrollable?

Tags: css

With absolute, it scrolls but doesn't get 100% in height:

```
.class {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1000000;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

With fixed, it gets 100% in height but doesn't scroll

```
.class {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1000000;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

I would like to avoid adding a fixed heigth to the child element and make it `overflow: scroll`

Comment: In your CSS with `position: absolute`, the container with `.class` will fill up the screen (or take on the dimensions of the nearest ancestor block with non-static positioning).  If you add enough content to the container, a vertical scroll bar will appear because the excess content will trigger a overflow condition (unless you set overflow to hidden).  The background color is painted on the `.class` container and does not apply to the overflowing content.  You need a nested container to work around this.  Please comment in your original post.

Comment: @MarcAudet [block level elements have a default overflow of `overflow: visible;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) which means that it will not start scrolling by default.  Instead it will just overflow its container and trigger scrolling on the nearest parent container which could go all the way up to the viewport.  This will result in a box that fills the height and width of the viewport but still has content that needs scrolled via the window.  The result is not pretty: http://jsbin.com/docojuyedi/1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add `overflow:auto` so that it scrolls if the content overflows the container.

```
.class {
    ...
    overflow:auto;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/kuqaqumude/1/edit?html,css,output

For more details concerning `overflow: auto` and `overflow: visible`, 
see:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow-clipping

Comment: if I add that to the first set of css where I use absolute, it doesn't work

Comment: what if the content doesn't overflow its container? I want the container to be full 100% height regadless

Comment: @rob.m [It still works](http://jsbin.com/yekoxisulo/2/edit).  You still need the `width:100%; height:100%`

Comment: This works for the initial appearance, but scrollTop JavaScript no longer works in fullscreen. Wish I could find a way to get that working as well.

Answer (score 5):

So first of all, if you want to have 100% height and width, you will have to define WHAT that is. So you have to tell the html/body that the size they have, is 100% width/height.

Now you don't want to let the page scroll down, if the text goes out of the div, because you will see white space if you do. So set overflow-y to scroll, so it will scroll inside the div, and not in the document itself.

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.fullwidth{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3ovLbL3q/1/)**